# Query column with semicolon into separate rows

Tags: mysql

Essentially, I have a table called `Table1` that has a column called `emails` that contains email addresses separated by semicolons.

**For example:**

**Row1:**

```
test1@gmail.com; test2@gmail.com
```

**Row2:**

```
test4@gmail.com; test5@gmail.com; test6@gmail.com
```

I would like to do a select query on the table to display each email on its own row each time the a semicolon is there to split. How can this be done?

Comment: Don't put more that one value in a column for a single row. This isn't the way SQL can work easily. Use a separate table and a JOIN. So its currently not possible in its current form.

Comment: Normalize your schema in the first place. See ["Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) (Spoiler: Yes, it is.).

Comment: I understand, is there a way to use temp tables in the query to split up the data?

Comment: look for splitting string functions

Comment: You can find many posts on Stack Overflow with the search terms: "split string into rows" or similar. I voted to mark this question as a duplicate, after I found one such post that had a good variety of different solutions. None of them are very convenient or elegant. It's better to store your data using one row per value, as other people have commented.

Comment: with mysql 8+ or mariadb 10.2+: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=4336e33289d44baf75333f6097554702  with earlier versions, you can use subqueries and joins but ideally need to know some maximum number of things that will need to be split

Answer (score -1):

its better to make an array or array of object and save data like..

```
[test1@gmail.com, test2@gmail.com, ...]
[{email: test1@gmail.com}, {email: test2@gmail.com}]
```

in that way you can easily get data by using query or by any programming language you are working on.

Comment: I am not currently able to modify the schema of the table, are there any other work arounds for handling a list separated by semicolons? Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: Are you using any backend language? or just mysql query ?

Comment: Yes I am also using PHP PDO

Comment: hmm, then try explode() method after simple select query, this will result same, 

   $str = "test@gamil.com; test1@gmail.com; test2@gmail.com";
then
   print_r (explode(";",$str));

hope this helps

Comment: here, ($str) is what you get from table